# how can I send multiple mails in a single smtp connection .I should be able to reuse the same smtp connection until all the mails are sent

Tags: c#, smtpclient

I have a C# application in which a new instance is being created to send each mail. Many SMTP have limited connection allowed to send the mails. So sometimes it blocks the flow of the mails. As a result, I need to find a way in which all these emails can be sent with a single Smtp connection. How can this be achieved?

Comment: Welcome to SO. You better read the [how-to-ask-page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) first then edit your question to show what you've tried so far.

Comment: It's not obvious why you **can't** do this already. Is there an issue in your code? We can't see it so it's hard to help or really understand the problem